# Using existing Eloquent models (and possibly other Laravel4 features) in CLI scripts?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on a project based on the Laravel 4 framework. The framework is awesome, the website works great, no problem with that.

But I also have to write several scripts, mostly DB maintenance tasks that will be scheduled in a crontab.

I'm looking for a way to write these scripts in the same *flavour* as the web-site code. Or at least, re-use the models and if possible some other framework features.

Is there a way to do that ? Thanks in advance :)

**Answer : Artisan Commands are indeed the way to go. Everything you need to know about these is available in [the Artisan Commands documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/commands).**

Comment: You can use the models without any problems in a non-web-context. What makes you think otherwise? BTw: most likely is you just want to create an [Artisan Command](http://four.laravel.com/docs/commands).

Comment: I tried including my models in a test script, but got many bootstrap-related errors, and after a couple hours trying, I thought it wasn't meat to be done that way. I'll try again :)

I'm going to read more about Artisan commands. Thanks !

Comment: @Nicolas if you're having specific problems with running artisan commands then you could write a question asking how to solve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for are Laravel 'tasks'. You can write scripts with the full toolset of your Laravel project and run them from the command line using the 'artisan' tool.

Answer (score -1):

Of course.

You can even make a route for your cron job, and call the route in your cron job command. Something like this:

```
wget http://yourdomain.com/cron/your-job
```

This way, you can use everything that Laravel 4 provides.

Comment: Oh no, please... it's 2013, we don't need to wget web pages in cron any more. Laravel has for many versions had a decent command line interface that can be used to generate [commands](http://four.laravel.com/docs/commands), perfect for being run by cron.