# Can I use Laravel in my PHP cron jobs?

Tags: php, cron, laravel

I've just started learning Laravel in the past couple days and I'm intrigued by its capabilities. On my current website, I am using several different PHP-based cron jobs and I'm wondering if it is possible to utilize Laravel in them.

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220785), so yes, have you tried it?

Comment: Honestly, no.  I really wasn't even sure where to begin and wasn't find the info I was looking for so I figured I would ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use Laravel's [tasks](http://laravel.com/docs/artisan/tasks) features.

Comment: Ah, perfect!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I haven't seen this in the tutorials I was browsing.  Do you have any task specific tutorials that you would recommend?